# Docker compose starts the jar package and how to import SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, docker-compose, jar, containers

I use docker-compose to start the jar package, enter the container, execute `keytool - import - lias SHA256with RSA - file cnsuning.cer - keystore cacerts`, and restart the service to access it. Why is it necessary to perform the same operation after a period of time when it doesn't work again?

I try to restart this,but it didn't work